# Can not Parse string to DateTime in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am trying to convert the `string` to `DateTime`. But I can not convert.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("16/11/2014", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Date==> " + dt);
```

The error is `FormatException`.

My input time format is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Please let me any idea to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have `dd/MM/yyyy` as a standard date and time format, but it has `MM/dd/yyyy` as a standard date and time format.

That's why it thinks your string is `MM/dd/yyyy` format, but since there is no [`16` as a month in Gregorian calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Description), you get [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

Instead of that, you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to specify *exact* format like;

```
string s = "16/11/2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you know your input format, you should specify it with `ParseExact:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I would always recommend being as explicit as you can be about date/time formats. It makes your intention very clear, and avoids the possibility of getting months and days the wrong way round.

As Soner has stated, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` uses `MM/dd/yyyy` as its short date pattern, as you can validate with:

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

As a mild plug, you might want to *consider* using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for your date/time handling - aside from anything else, that allows you to treat a date as a date, rather than as a date and time...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and Explanation.. Your and Soner explanations are super.. Thanks..